# Deleting a line from c++ file by giving a word

Tags: c++, file, csv

I have made a Quizlet code to save a word with its translation(in Russian) in csv file.
So, the 'add' and 'read' functions work perfectly but I have been trying to make  the 'delete' function remove a line when I give a substring of that line.

update: I am trying to copy all the lines except the one that i wanna delete to a new file and then rename it.
but when the new file is created, it is empty!

ex: in the file, line 1:  apple яблоко.

input: apple, and then the entire is being deleted.

here is my code: I just have a problem in void quizlet::DeleteWord()

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class quizlet {
private:
    std::string filename;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

public:
    quizlet(std::string filename) : filename(filename) {}

    void AddWord(std::string, std::string);
    vector<string> ReadAllWords();
    void DeleteWord();
};

void quizlet::AddWord(std::string word, std::string translation) {
   cout << "Write a word and its translation separated by a space:" << std::endl;
   cin >> word >> translation;


   // file pointer
    fstream fout;

    // opens an existing csv file or creates a new file.
    fout.open("words.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
    // Insert the data to file
    fout <<word<<" "<<translation<<endl;

    std::cout << "Saved new card: " << word << "/" << translation << std::endl;
}

vector<string> quizlet::ReadAllWords() {

    // File pointer
    fstream fin;

    // Open an existing file
    fin.open("words.txt", ios::in);




    // Read the Data from the file
    // as String Vector
    vector <string> rows;
    string line, word, temp;


    while (getline(fin, line)) {

        cout << line << std::endl;
        rows.push_back(line);
        stringstream s(line);

    }

    return rows;







   }


void quizlet::DeleteWord() {

    string line;
    fstream fin;
    fstream fout;
    fin.open("words.txt", ios::in);
    fout.open("new.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
    string token;
    cin>>token;

    vector <string> lines;
    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        if (line.find(token) != string::npos) {
            cout << line << endl;
            fin << line << endl;
            cout<<"the line has been deleted!";
            //remove (line);
        }
    }

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    remove("words.txt");
    rename("new.txt", "words.txt");
    cout << "\nChanges has Successfully been made...... Data Saved\n" << endl;

}




int main() {
    auto Quizlet = quizlet("words.txt");
    string word, translation;
    while (true) {
        std::string command;
        std::cin >> command;



        if (command == "add") {

            Quizlet.AddWord(word, translation);

        } else if (command == "read") {
            Quizlet.ReadAllWords();

        }
        else if (command == "delete") {
            Quizlet.DeleteWord();

        }



        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your edit killed syntax highlighting somehow... Instead of `std::vector<std::string> words;`, store a vector-of-lines, e.g. `std::vector<std::string> lines;` and that way all you need to do it iterate over your vector checking if the current word is a substring of the `line` and then use `vector.erase()` on that line to delete it. You can always grab each word from any line by creating a `stringstream` of the lines and calling `getline` wtih a comma-delimiter when needed.

Comment: No need to call stringstream, you can also just get the string from the iterator of the vector and use std::string functions like erase and store the new one back into the vector

Comment: (**note:** if you rely on `\`\`\`` to provide a fixed format, you must follow the opening  `\`\`\`` with the language type to get syntax-hightlighting, e.g.  `\`\`\`c++` . You get auto syntax-highlighting if you just indent it all by 4-spaces.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after trying for a long time. 
I got this code and it works perfectly  with no errors.

thank you all!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class quizlet {
private:
    std::string filename;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

public:
    quizlet(std::string filename) : filename(filename) {}

    void AddWord(std::string, std::string);
    vector<string> ReadAllWords();
    void DeleteWord(std::string);
};

void quizlet::AddWord(std::string word, std::string translation) {
   cout << "Write a word and its translation separated by a space:" << std::endl;
   cin >> word >> translation;

   // file pointer
    fstream fout;

    // opens an existing csv file or creates a new file.
    fout.open("words.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
    // Insert the data to file
    fout << word << " " << translation << endl;

    std::cout << "Saved new card: " << word << "/" << translation << std::endl;
}

vector<string> quizlet::ReadAllWords() {

    // File pointer
    fstream fin;

    // Open an existing file
    fin.open("words.txt", ios::in);

    // Read the Data from the file
    // as String Vector
    vector <string> rows;
    string line, word, temp;

    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        cout << line << std::endl;
        rows.push_back(line);
        stringstream s(line);
    }
    return rows;
}

void quizlet::DeleteWord(string token) {
    string line;
    fstream fin;
    fstream fout;
    fin.open("words.txt", ios::in);
    fout.open("new.txt",ios::out | ios::app);

    cin >> token;

    vector<string> lines;
    while(getline(fin, line)) {
        if(line.find(token) == string::npos)  {
            fout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    fout.close();
    fin.close();

    remove("words.txt");
    rename("new.txt", "words.txt");
    cout << "\nChanges has Successfully been made...... Data Saved\n" << endl;

}

int main() {
    auto Quizlet = quizlet("words.txt");
    string word, translation, token;
    while(true) {
        std::string command;
        std::cin >> command;

        if(command == "add") {
            Quizlet.AddWord(word, translation);
        } else if(command == "read") {
            Quizlet.ReadAllWords();
        } else if(command == "delete") {
            Quizlet.DeleteWord(token);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post-update edit:

My original answer now makes much more sense given what you are trying to do. You should read the whole file in at once, make any additions and deletions in-memory you want, then overwrite the original file with the whole, new, list.

Original answer:

Consider reading the file into memory via a `std::map<std::string,std::wstring>` instead of a `std::vector<std::string>` of lines in the file.

Using this approach, adding and deleting a word and its translation is simple.

Adding:

```
//if-guard only needed if you want to protect against overwriting already-existing words.
auto found_iter = cards.find(word);
if(found_iter == cards.end()) {
    cards.insert_or_assign(word, translation);
}
```

Deleting:

```
auto found_iter = cards.find(word);
if(found_iter != cards.end()) {
    cards.erase(found_iter);
}
```

Writing it back to the file is as simple as looping over the collection:

```
for(const auto& [word,translation] : cards) {
    fout << word << ' ' << translation << '\n';
}
fout.close();
```